# How to mount blind over awkward window casing

Tags: blinds, window-frame

I'm mounting a new blind.  The brackets require two holes, horizontally.  I want to mount them to studs.  It's a pull-down blind that will be constantly handled by many people, sometimes roughly.

In the photo, the upper pair of holes don't work because there is no wood behind the drywall.  I don't want to mount to the casing, it will break off eventually.

The lower pair of holes don't work because they are inset, so the outer edge of the frame prevents the blind from mating properly.

I could replace the whole blind with an inner-mounting one but there is just nowhere suitable to do that on this window, as far as I can see.

There is a 2x4 block behind the wall in the region where I drew the yellow rectangle.  I think I have to mount the blind there.  And to clear the casing I have to mount it on a 1/2 inch block of wood, for which I think I'll use white composite so it will hopefully look like part of the blind's case which is white.

Any better ideas?
[image]

Here is a photo showing the framing behind the casing, and I've added a green rectangle roughly in the position of the upper casing and green dots showing the new lower and upper holes, and the even higher ones I think I need to use.
[image]

Comment: Imagine the 'block' goes right across the window, not just where marked it?  Think your idea for a piece of white wood is good.  Should be a header just above the window, but think the casing goes beyond  it(miss it on the top holes).

Comment: Yes the block goes all the way across the window from stud to stud.  Yes regarding the header, it's too low for this bracket and there's space above it.

Comment: Is there a chance there was a larger/higher window there at one time?  Placement of that block seems odd, almost where a header would be.  Would expect short studs going up.

Comment: Sorry, was trying to keep it simple.  Yes you are right.  The "block" *is* the header.  There *was* a larger window (from 1896 to 1975ish) There is some lighter framing, good enough for mounting, behind the casing but that's not the header.  There is space between that and the actual header.  I actually have a picture, which I'll add now since you seem to have enough interest .... thank you!

Comment: You might ask why I didn't add blocking to that space while I had it open.  Please don't.  :)

Comment: !/2 inch spacer or what you need and screws to go into the header, those blinds will never fall down.  Unless there was a very good reason, the only thing I might put there is insulation.